# C++/CLI how to pass integer pointer to C++ API

Tags: c++-cli

Looks like I am doing a basic mistake here. I have a 3 party C++ library(test.dll) in which there is a API defined as follows. And I am invoking this APi by loading the library, getting the API and invoke. I am new to C++ CLI, any pointers to solve the issue will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

3rd part library exported API
FUNCTION_EXPORT void STDCALL GetVersion(UINT16& version);
typedef void (STDCALL *GETVERSION)(UINT16);

I need to call it from C++ Cli

Header file

```
    MyTest.h

namespace MyTest {

public ref class TestClass
{

public:
    HMODULE module;
    String^ version;

    void TestMethod()
};
}
```

2. Cpp file

   ```
   MyTest.cpp
   namespace MyTest {
   TestClass::TestMethod()
   {
   this->module = LoadLibrary(engineDllPath);
   if (!this->module)
   {
       return String::Format("LoadLibrary failed");
   };

   // Get engine version
   GETVERSION GetVersionApi = (GETVERSION)GetProcAddress(module, "GetVersion");
   if (!GetVersionApi)
   {
       return;
   }


   UINT16 major;
   GetVersionApi(&uiMajor);
   }
   }
   ```

Getting compilation error 
 error C2664: 'void (UINT16 &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'UINT16 *' to 'UINT16 &'

Code snippet is to give an idea what I am trying. The main issue is here
UINT16 major;
GetVersionApi(&uiMajor);

what will be the correct way of calling it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetVersion(UINT16& version);
```

That's not an integer pointer, that's an integer reference. You don't need to type any extra characters to pass a reference.

```
GetVersionApi(uiMajor);
//            ^ no "&"
```